# Can't create by "XXX_params", though params are available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newer to Ruby on Rails.I got a problem as following:
My rails environment is ruby2.0.0 ,rails 4.1.1

1,First,here is my Energies Controller:

```
 class EnergiesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :all_energies, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
        before_action :set_energies, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
        respond_to :html, :js
    ........
    def create
       puts "in create method"
       @energy = Energy.create(energy_params)
       puts "create method end"
   end
   .......
   private
   .......
     def energy_params
         puts "in get_params method"
         params.require(:energy).permit(:title, :capacity, :generation, :power_category, :location, :longitude, :latitude, :energy_role)
         puts params
         puts "get_params method end"
    end
 end
```

2,my log output is:

```
    Started POST "/energies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-29 18:44:25 +0800
    Processing by EnergiesController#create as JS                 
     Parameters{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"rliBtHNMG/7PvivOE3WT4Z2K0MY/d9WnUYRFu04imNk=", "energy"=>{"title"=>"qwe", "capacity"=>"1", "generation"=>"12", "power_category"=>"12", "location"=>"12", "longitude"=>"12", "latitude"=>"123", "energy_role"=>"13"}, "commit"=>"Create Energy"}
    in get_all method
    get_all method end
    **in create method**
    **in get_params method**
    {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rliBtHNMG/7PvivOE3WT4Z2K0MY/d9WnUYRFu04imNk=", "energy"=>{"title"=>"qwe", "capacity"=>"1", "generation"=>"12", "power_category"=>"12", "location"=>"12", "longitude"=>"12", "latitude"=>"123", "energy_role"=>"13"}, "commit"=>"Create Energy", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"energies"}
    **get_params method end**
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "energies" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)   [["created_at", "2014-08-29 10:44:25.440007"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-29 10:44:25.440007"]]
   (171.5ms)  commit transaction
   **create method end**
   in create_js file
   Energy Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "energies".* FROM "energies"
   Rendered energies/_energy.html.erb (4.2ms)
   Rendered energies/create.js.erb (11.4ms)
   Completed 200 OK in 195ms (Views: 17.9ms | ActiveRecord: 172.4ms)
```

AS you can see, the method get_param looks like run properly, but when the the code 
**"@energy = Energy.create(energy_params)"** run, it will be translated to the SQL :
**"SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "energies" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-29 10:44:25.440007"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-29 10:44:25.440007"]]"**

Actually, it ran alright at first,but i don't know why it suddenly doesn't work.Much thanks for any help.

Comment: Are there any validations on the model ?

Comment: Can you add your view form code ?

Comment: thank you for your kind.@BroiSatse has helped me solved it. I am a newer to SF, too. When i wanted to add my view code just now, i can't click the "save" button. So it's a bit slow for me to give my thanks. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def energy_params
  puts "in get_params method"
  params.require(:energy).permit(:title, :capacity, :generation, :power_category, :location, :longitude, :latitude, :energy_role)
  puts params
  puts "get_params method end"
end
```

Remove all the unnecessary lines. Ruby methods returns the value returned by its last executed line - in this case this is always nil (value returned from puts).

```
def energy_params
  params.require(:energy).permit(:title, :capacity, :generation, :power_category, :location, :longitude, :latitude, :energy_role)
end
```

Comment: Good catch!  The key here is that the value returned from a method is **the last line of the method** if the last line of the method `energy_params` is a `puts` you get back nil and **not** the values in `params.require`

Comment: it really works. thank you very much. Actually, my original code was just like yours. But as i mentioned, i'm a newer. so i want to know the order of the code excute,so i add some puts. I really haven't realize the problem is here. Thanks a lot